# What does “ごゆるりと” mean?

Tags: adverbs

What does this mean:「まあ、ごゆるりと」?

Comment: What context is this phrase in? If you had to try to translate this, how would you approach it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“まあ” is an interjection, implying “Well, Please.”

“ごゆるりと” is a polite, but a bit oldish expression for “ゆっくりと – slowly,” meaning “Take as much time as you wish,” hence “relax,” “take it easy,” “behave as freely as you can.”

“ごゆるりと” can be used in such a way as:

> - “どうぞ、ごゆるりとお過ごしください” – Please take it easy (Make yourself at home, or Stay here as long as you like)
> - "ごゆるりとお行き遊ばせ - Please go slowly,”

either in an elegant, but antiquated way.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it's a somewhat old-fashioned way of saying "relax/take it easy/etc". A more modern equivalent would be ごゆっくり.